# Fetch'ing a file from local app cache with `file://` URI on Android using React-Native returns "unexpected url"

Tags: android, react-native, fetch

I'm running into an issue fetching a file from the local filesystem using React-Native 0.56.0.

The file uri has the format `file://<path-to-cache>/filename.mp4`, and calling `await fetch(uri)` throws an error in React's bundled whatwg-fetch library. The trace itself looks like:

```
ExceptionsManager.js:84 TypeError: Network request failed
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onerror (whatwg-fetch.js:504)
    at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (event-target.js:171)
    at XMLHttpRequest.setReadyState (XMLHttpRequest.js:575)
    at XMLHttpRequest.__didCompleteResponse (XMLHttpRequest.js:391)
    at XMLHttpRequest.js:504
    at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (EventEmitter.js:190)
    at MessageQueue.__callFunction (MessageQueue.js:344)
    at MessageQueue.js:107
    at MessageQueue.__guard (MessageQueue.js:291)
    at MessageQueue.callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue (MessageQueue.js:106)
```

It looks like the whatwg-fetch lib is eating the underlying error, and when I went in and logged the event that triggered this error, it contained the message:

`unexpected url: file://...`.

I have a feeling that the issue may be related to a recent upgrade from RN 0.55.4 to RN 0.56.0, but I haven't been able to successfully downgrade and test yet, and wondering if anybody's seen this issue before.

My goal is to get a local video file as a blob, check the size, and then upload the file to Firebase storage. The flow looks something as follows:

```
class myComponent {
    uploadFile() {
        const videoUri = "file://<path_to_video>";
        // Error occurs on this call
        const response = await fetch(videoUri);
        const blob = await response.blob();
        if (blob.data.size > MAX_DATA_SIZE) {
             throw Exception("Video too big!");
        }
        upload(blob) // upload to Firebase
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Button onPress={this.uploadFile} title="Upload file" />
        );
    }
}
```

The `VideoPlayer` from the `react-native-video-processing` library is happily playing the video at `videoUri`, so it doesn't seem to me like an issue with the uri itself.

Comment: What do you want to do? play video file from local system?

Comment: @Rubycon, I am fetching the file data to upload to cloud storage. Updating question to describe the exact flow.

Comment: @RahulGupta-Iwasaki I'm using RN 0.55.4 and having the same issue. did you manage to solve this?

Comment: @0xori, unfortunately I have not figured it out yet XD I just disabled the client-side filesize check that was depending on fetch.

Comment: @RahulGupta-Iwasaki for me it was due to remote JS debugging